# Select * Where not Exists gives me errors

Tags: php, mysql, join, not-exists

Ok my objective is to query table 1 for data, but make sure that the data has not already been presented by checking in table 2.

Each data has an ID which is under the UUID column.

`Select *  FROM table1 Where Not Exists
  (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.UUID = table1.UUID);`

But I have researched and I have tried every possible way to write that query and I keep getting:

"ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.UUID = table1.UUID) at line 1"

Any help?

Also some of the articles I found on the internet suggest that a join would be more efficient, but others state that where not exists is better. Which is the more efficient route?

Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: i am trying to present new data everytime. table2 is the "already read table" and table1 is the database. I want to make sure an entry in table1 does not exist in table 2 before presenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have to that like this:

```
SELECT UUID, ...
FROM Table1
WHERE UUID NOT IN
        (SELECT UUID FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.UUID = Table1.UUID)
```

this means that the query selects all records from table1 where `UUID` in table1 *does not exist* in table2

Comment: +1 the solution is so obvious after you typed it out. Good job :)

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `table` with `table1`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.UUID = table1.UUID);
```

Comment: Beat me to the answer button! +1.

Comment: Sir mind if i ask this? Doesn't it needs to have a field or column after `WHERE`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I did have table1 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: again sorry. I changed the names of the tables to make it easier to read and made a typo in typing it on here.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `LEFT JOIN` and check for `NULL` instead.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON a.UUID=b.UUID
WHERE b.UUID IS NULL
```